# Sum of Normal Random Variables | Different Dimensions

Tags: r, normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

I would like to generate one random numer $single\sim N(0,1)$ and create the vector that contains only this one number: $one = [single, single, ..., single]$ . Later, I would like to combine with vector of multiple random numbers $several \sim N(0,1)$ using $weight$:

$New=weight*one+\sqrt(1-weight^2)*several$

Is it $New\sim N(0,1)?$

I thought so, because both $one$, and $several$ are random and generated from normal distribution. However, right now, I am not so sure. $one$ is in fact a vector of the same values so it might be treateat as constant here.

I tried to use R code to check below:

```py
results<-matrix(ncol=4,nrow<-0)

colnames(results)<-c("sd(Normal)", "mean(Normal)", "sd(New)", "mean(new)")

for(i in 1:100000){

  set.seed(i)
  one<-rnorm(1,mean=0,sd=1)
  several<-rnorm(4000, mean=0, sd=1)

  weight<-0.20

  NORMAL<-several #this is N(0,1)
  NEW<- weight*one+sqrt(1-weight^2)*several #not sure if N(0,1)

  vector<- c(sd(NORMAL), mean(NORMAL), sd(NEW), mean(NEW))
  results<- rbind(results, vector)
}

colMeans(results)*100 #BP
sqrt(1-weight^2)*100 #BP
```

Results:

```
      sd(Normal)   mean(Normal)      sd(New)       mean(new) 
      99.99548850  -0.00423462       97.97516937   0.04152757
```

The results sd(New) are very similar to the $sqrt(1-weight^2)*100=97.97959$ and that raised my question about $New$ variable.

Comment: Mathematically, your question doesn't make sense until you can explain what it means to add a scalar to a vector.  Could you edit the post to clarify this point?

Comment: Thanks for your comment: I have edited to make sure we are adding vectors.

Comment: In symbols, are you asking about the distribution of the vector $(Y_i)$ where $Y_i=a X + b Z_i$ with $a,b$ constants with $a^2+b^2=1,$ $X$ Normally distributed,  $Z_i$ multinormally distributed independently of $X$?

Comment: Yes, in R set.seed(1) we have: $X=[0.7083495, 0.7083495, 0.7083495, ...], Z_i = [-0.03846413,  0.94647475, 0.84385583, ... ]$ wheras $ Y_i = [0.1039829,1.0690220,  0.9684764]$ I am not sure if $Y_i ~N(0,1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$New=weight*one+\sqrt(1-weight^2)*several$ change to
$$Y_{ij}=wX_i +\sqrt{1-w^2}Z_{ij}$$ where $X,Z$ follows standard normal distribution and independent from each other, and $ 0\le w\le 1$.

Let $\gamma_i = wX_i$, then $\gamma_i \sim N(0,w^2)$. Let $\epsilon_{ij} = \sqrt{1-w^2}Z_{ij}$ then $\epsilon \sim N(0, 1-w^2)$. 
$$Y_{ij}=\gamma_i+\epsilon_{ij}$$ It is the random part in the mixed model.
Let see the whole picture of $Y_{ij}$. Let $i=1,...,I$ and $j=1,..., J$. Let $Y = (Y_{11} ,Y_{12},...,Y_{1J},...,Y_{i1},...,Y_{IJ})'$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
Y_{11}\\
Y_{12}\\
...\\
Y_{1J}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
1& 1 &0 &...&0\\
1& 0& 1 &...&0\\
...&...&...&...&...\\
1&0&0&...&1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
\gamma_1\\
\epsilon_{11}\\
\epsilon_{12}\\
...\\
\epsilon_{1J}
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$Var\begin{pmatrix} 
\gamma_1\\
\epsilon_{11}\\
\epsilon_{12}\\
...\\
\epsilon_{1J}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
w^2& 0 & ...&0\\
0&1-w^2&...&0\\
...&...&...&...\\
0&0&...&1-w^2
\end{pmatrix}$$
Following $Var(AX)=AVar(X)A'$, you can get
$$Var\begin{pmatrix} 
Y_{11}\\
Y_{12}\\
...\\
Y_{1J}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
1& 1 &0 &...&0\\
1& 0& 1 &...&0\\
...&...&...&...&...\\
1&0&0&...&1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
w^2& 0 & ...&0\\
0&1-w^2&...&0\\
...&...&...&...\\
0&0&...&1-w^2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
1& 1 &0 &...&0\\
1& 0& 1 &...&0\\
...&...&...&...&...\\
1&0&0&...&1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
1&w^2&...&w^2\\
w^2& 1&...&w^2\\
...&...&...&...\\
w^2&w^2&...&1
\end{pmatrix}_{J\times J} =\Sigma$$

Then $Y\sim N(0, I\otimes \Sigma)$.

What you did is setting $I=1$ and $J=4000$. The sample variance of $Y_{1j}, j=1,...,4000$ is the estimate of conditional variance $Var(Y_{ij}|i=1) = Var(Y_{1j}|\gamma_1) = Var(\epsilon_{1j}) = 1-w^2$

If you want to verify the unconditional variance of $Y_{ij}$ being 1, you can set $I = 200$ and $J=20$. and re-run roue code.

Comment: Many thanks for your help - I see that you put a lot of effort into writing the answer.
I just want to clarify this point: $\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 
1&w^2&...&w^2\\
w^2& 1&...&w^2\\
...&...&...&...\\
w^2&w^2&...&1
\end{pmatrix}_{I\times I}$ how did you get this one?

Comment: The details were added in the Answer. Need matrix skill.

Comment: All is clear now, many many thanks  user158565!